# How to control charge on a high-voltage capacitor after voltage multiplier?

Tags: capacitor, high-voltage, multiplier

Can anyone think of an electronic way to control the charge on a high-voltage capacitor that is fed by a multi-stage voltage multiplier?

I can control the charge on the way up by controlling the input voltage to the multiplier (multiplied voltage output is proportional to DC input voltage on the multiplier). But once the output voltage and load capacitor reach 20-50KV, I can't think of a way to bring the voltage back down under control.

You could think of Van de Graaf generators, Tesla coils, and voltage multipliers as models. I'm trying to think of a way to control the charges produced by all of these devices. (As a thought experiment for now, since I can't figure out how to design or build anything that seems credible for the job.)

Shorting it out *physically* seems to be the only obvious way, all in one go. But I would rather have an electronic way of control, if possible, so that I control the amount of charge (and therefore voltage) in the load capacitor. The problem is that no transistor (or electronic switch) that I can find can withstand the 20-50KV across its collector-emitter terminals.

If it helps any, my envisioned capacitor is maybe 100pF (by calculation; I haven't built anything for it yet) with tiny current levels of 10-50 microamps and charges of 3-5 micro-Coulombs.

Balancing the multiplier current against a bleeder resistor current doesn't seem like it would be workable (by calculation) because even a tiny bleeder current would require *hundreds* of 10meg resistors for 50KV. Keep in mind the multiplier only produces 100 microamps.

Comment: If you just want FETs that can withstand such high drain-source voltages, some arrangement of several of [these](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ixys/IXTH02N450HV/IXTH02N450HV-ND/5031665) in series might work (or some other high-voltage FET, of course). Their \$R_{DS,on}\$ is pretty high, but with the low currents you're talking about that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: One [4CM2500KG/X2274](https://www.relltubes.com/filebase/en/src/Datasheets/4cm2500kg.pdf) can handle \$27\:\text{kV}\$ at \$190\:\text{A}\$. And you can regulate the plate current -- it's a tetrode. Be sure to check out its filament/heater current, too!

Comment: Not supposed to promote 'brands', but Caddock makes high value 10M to 100M ceramic wafer resistors rated for 40KV, 0.05% tolerance, about $75 USD each. 2 of them in series would be good to bleed off the charge slowly. Or with a PWM controller they could be part of a servo-loop to maintain a fixed voltage.

Comment: You might consider a second capacitor - initially discharged - then connected to the charged one (via some megohms to limit current surges). Ratio of capacitances controls voltage ratio. (Assuming suitable relay or switch technology)

Comment: Everyone, thank you for your ideas. The FETs have a 4.5KV rating, but wouldn't I have to balance the 45KV evenly across the FETs with resistors?  Using switches/relays to switch 20-50KV is difficult or not workable (like the water-cooled tetrode that is 18inches in size and requires pumps). The Caddock resistors have workable values (1000Meg) and workable voltage ratings (25-32KV). I didn't know about them. They might work. I will investigate further. Thank you!

Comment: The Caddock resistors are about 110 USD each in minimum packs of 10, which puts them out of my price range for my little project. But at least they might be a way to balance the input flow of charge (with a duty cycle) against a constant outflow through the resistor.